# SQL query for retrieval

Tags: sql

This is my table structure

```
id   state     city   lat    lon
1     erer      wer    34     34
2     ffff      dfd    44     33
1     fds       rw     0      45
```

Using this, I have to retrieve the data without duplicates from the above table. If I have to retrieve data with id `1` and `2`, I used `Group by id`. Now I also have to check one more condition, whether the `lat > 0`.

```
select *
  from table
 group by id and lat > 0
```

But still data with 0 is also being retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
select *
from table
WHERE lat > 0 
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING`

```
select *
from table
group by id
having lat > 0
```